# Delete-Statement with Union in subquery won't work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Query with `Union-Statement` where I retrieve all `UserIds` which are present in the `Requester` & `Provider` `Column` of the `table` Orders.

```
SELECT Requester
FROM Orders
UNION 
SELECT Provider
FROM Orders

This query yields some 7000 results in under a second.
```

Now i have table named '`Persons`' where those `UserIds` are `linked to the persons data`.
Using the above query i would like to clean this table and only keep the UserIds that are present in the   result of the union-statement above.

So I made the following delete-statement:

```
DELETE FROM
Persons
WHERE
UserId NOT IN(

SELECT Requester
FROM Orders
UNION 
SELECT Provider
FROM Orders
)
```

Yet this query refuses to execute (even after 5 minutes waiting). What could be the reason for my query to fail? Am I not allowed to use `UNION` as Statement in the subquery here?

**Note:** 
following [MySQL DELETE FROM with UNION subquery by IN condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225080/mysql-delete-from-with-union-subquery-by-in-condition) didn't solve it for me.

Comment: What happens when you replace the 'delete from' with a 'select * from'? Another approach - store the result of the union query in a temporary table and use that in the 'delete' query.

Comment: Slow as hell. But yielding results. Could it be because i'm overextending the `In `statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query works.  It just takes a long time.  Perhaps the following will be more efficient:

```
DELETE FROM Persons
    WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT DocAuthor FROM Document WHERE DocAuthors IS NOT NULL) AND
          UserId NOT IN (SELECT DocActualApprovers FROM Document WHERE DocActualApprovers IS NOT NULL);
```

Then, for performance, it would be best to have (at least) two indexes: `Document(DocAuthor)` and `DocAuthor(DocActualApprovers)`.  Note that your original query will delete nothing if either `DocAuthor` or `DocActualApprovers` is ever `NULL`.  Presumably, this is not what you want; hence, the `where` clause.

EDIT:

You might find that `not exists` works faster:

```
DELETE FROM Persons p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DocAuthor FROM Document d WHERE d.DocAuthor = p.UserId) AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT DocActualApprovers FROM Document WHERE d.DocActualApprovers = p.UserId);
```

The same indexes would help here.

Comment: Thank you for point me to the ´Null´problem! Your query works but still slow. Somehow I feel like the `IN-statement`is hurting my performance