# MySQL - How to delete related rows in a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

For example if a customer is deleted, all the related row on other table(S) will be deleted. How to do that mysql, it's a hours i tried many solution but noone worked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCMS4.png)

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer without knowing what database you are using and without understanding what the foreign key constraints look like. That said, `Customer_Addresses` has a foreign key with cascade delete then deleting the entry from that table will delete data from `Customer` and `Addresses`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **easiest way** to achieve that is design related tables with **`ON DELETE CASCADE` option**.

Basically, when you **design a database table that has a foreign key** (primary key on other table), you can **set `ON DELETE CASCADE` for that foreign key**. That means that when a **record is deleted on the primary table** (the table where this foreign key is the primary key) **all related records on other tables are also deleted**.

Therefore, you don't need to think on create "crazy" queries to delete related data on multiple tables.

You can learn more about `ON DELETE CASCADE` [here](https://mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade)

Answer (score 2):

You have to `DELETE` the Address first, the Customers, and after the relation
Or you can try to use DELETE cascate ... but be careful http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/ 
see this too : [MySQL on delete cascade. Test Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185811/mysql-on-delete-cascade-test-example)

`DELETE FROM Addresses WHERE AddressID IN (SELECT AddressID FROM Custormers_Addresses WHERE CustormerID = ID)`

THEN .. Delete the customer
`DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ID`

THEN .. delete the relacion
`DELETE AddressID FROM Custormers_Addresses WHERE CustormerID = ID`

Comment: You might try and use a `UNION` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225080/mysql-delete-from-with-union-subquery-by-in-condition) amongst other places. Alternatively consider using a transactional database like InnoDB, unless you have truly massive amount of data.